# Does Mail support multiple email accounts?

Tags: macos, email, mail.app

Does Mail support multiple email accounts? If yes, how can I set them up?

Comment: @Chealion: I do believe you've misspelled "Mail.app" in that tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it does. From within Mail, open up preferences, select the Accounts tab, and click on the small "+" button in the lower left-hand corner of the window. This will run the "Add Account" wizard to guide you through the rest of the steps.